# Azure DevOps Sprint Selection

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure devops when I go to the sprints section of the boards tab, I am presented with a sprint selection screen, which makes me choose "continue where I left off", "My favorite sprints", "My Team Sprints" or "All Sprints". All of these only have the current sprint in them, is there a way to just bypass this selection screen and go right to the current sprint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you are on an older version of their UI? When I navigate to the section you describe, it shows what you are expecting.

For example, navigating to Organization / Project / Boards / Sprints for our team brings us to the taskboard right away without the additional screen (Masked for privacy):

[image: Sprints Section of Boards Tab]

Another thing to check, if you have more than one team sprint you are subscribed to, you may be defaulted to see all sprints. If that's the case, then that is why you are being directed to the selection screen. Check which team sprint is selected, as indicated below:

[image: all team sprints]

If you choose a specific team's sprint, it should navigate directly to the taskboard without going through the selection screen.